# Design a "Wizard" set of screens on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, wizard

I want to build a guided "Wizard" set of screens on the iPad.  So there is one master screen with N sub-steps in it that are guided through.  You should be able to go backwards and forwards through the steps, but also have a "Home" button that goes to the base step.

So the technical challenge is: how does a screen unload itself and load another screen that is the next in the sequence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use a UINavigationController (possibly as a ModalViewController) as it is intended to be used that way, with a chain of sub view controllers for each step of configuration. Share a single object throughout your viewcontrollers to keep track of the user progress and voila!

You could use a single UIViewController with different full screen views being showed/hidden but I don't really see the point of doing it that way: the UINavigationController will also feel familiar for your users, where a custom solution might not.

Comment: Thanks!  This answer made more sense to me once I learned that you can use the UINavigationController in a transparent way without having it look any different.
